# Html and tables

Tags: html, html-table

I have such table: http://jsfiddle.net/jDTTx/

I can't understand how to split cell with text **1** into 2 horizontal cells. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Can you make a mockup screen shot of what you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to set the rowspan for all of the cells in the row above it to 2, and leave the row span for the two cells which you would like to appear split as 1.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jDTTx/6/

```
    <table border="1" style="border: 2px solid black; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; font-weight: bold" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead style="background-color: gray; color: white">
            <tr>
                <td>№</td>
                <td>Час</td>
                <td>АУД. 402</td>
                <td>АУД. 402<sup>A</sup></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">1</td>
                <td rowspan="2">8<sup><u>00</u></sup> - 9<sup><u>20</u></sup></td>
                <td>1a</td>
                <td rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1b</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>9<sup><u>35</u></sup> - 10<sup><u>55</u></sup></td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>11<sup><u>15</u></sup> - 12<sup><u>35</u></sup></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: That's almost what I need but it splits my row vertically, I need horizontally. Can you help?

Comment: I'm sorry, sometimes I get vertical and horizontal confused ;)  See my edits! :)

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your cell:

```
<div style="border-bottom:solid 1px black">1a</div><div>1b</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jDTTx/7/